# Why is this for loop duplicating data in the output - Python?

Tags: python

I'm listing servers in GCP and writing them to confluence.

For some reason this list function is giving me duplicate output but ONLY if I iterate through a list:

```
def list_instances(compute,gcp_env_list,gcp_zones_list,date):
    delete_from_collection(date)
    project_id = 'company1'
    items = []
    zones = ['us-east1-b','us-east1-c','us-east1-d','us-east4-c']
    for zone in zones:
        try:
            result = compute.instances().list(project=project_id, zone=zone, filter='status=running').execute()
            items = result['items']
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error has occurred: {e}")
        if items:
            for item in items:
                instance_id = item['id']
                name = item['name']
                print(f"Name of the instance is: {name}")
                timestamp = item['creationTimestamp']
                private_ip = item['networkInterfaces'][0]['networkIP']
                instance_dict = {'Instance ID': instance_id, 'Name': name,'Network Interfaces': private_ip,'Timestamp': timestamp,}
                insert_coll(instance_dict,date)
```

This gives me the following output. These are all duplicated:

```
Instance iD         Name                                                         Network Interfaces  Timestamp
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-styx-5                     xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-08T01:17:04.721-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-styx-5                     xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-08T01:17:04.721-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-boca-us-east1-6                                   xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-04-12T07:47:58.100-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-boca-us-east1-6                                   xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-04-12T07:47:58.100-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-std-p-1                    xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-08T23:58:19.587-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-std-p-1                    xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-08T23:58:19.587-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-std-p-2                    xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-09T01:01:36.145-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-std-p-2                    xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-09T01:01:36.145-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-sql16-e1d-3                                       xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-07T11:18:41.098-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-sql16-e1d-3                                       xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-07T11:18:41.098-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-postgres-partner-e1d-4                            xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-11T08:27:35.952-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-postgres-partner-e1d-4                            xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-11T08:27:35.952-07:00
```

I had to heavily anonymize the data so that it bears no resemblance to the servers at work. But you can see the duplication happening.

If even duplicates the info if you reduce the zones list to one element that I know has servers in it: `zones = ['us-east1-d]`

However, if I remove the loop for the zones list and hard code one zone, then the duplication stops happening:

```
def list_instances(compute,gcp_env_list,gcp_zones_list,date):
    delete_from_collection(date)
    project_id = 'company1'
    items = []
    zone  = 'us-east1-d'
    try:
        result = compute.instances().list(project=project_id, zone=zone, filter='status=running').execute()
        items = result['items']
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error has occurred: {e}")
    for item in items:
        instance_id = item['id']
        name = item['name']
        print(f"Name of the instance is: {name}")
        timestamp = item['creationTimestamp']
        private_ip = item['networkInterfaces'][0]['networkIP']
        instance_dict = {'Instance ID': instance_id, 'Name': name,'Network Interfaces': private_ip,'Timestamp': timestamp,}
        insert_coll(instance_dict,date)
```

This is the output when I remove the for loop for the zones:

```
Instance iD         Name                                                         Network Interfaces  Timestamp
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-styx-5                     xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-08T01:17:04.721-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-boca-us-east1-6                                   xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-04-12T07:47:58.100-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-std-p-1                    xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-08T23:58:19.587-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx gcloud-department-kube-department-std-p-2                    xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-09T01:01:36.145-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-sql16-e1d-3                                       xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-07T11:18:41.098-07:00
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx department-postgres-partner-e1d-4                            xx.xx.xx.xx         2021-05-11T08:27:35.952-07:00
```

Why does the data duplicate only if I give it a list to cycle through?  How can I correct this?

Comment: Have you [done any debugging?](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
[Stepped through the code with a debugger?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) You should observe the value of the `items` variable as you step through and see if it has what you expect. Also, please read the page about providing a [mre]. There is no way strangers on the internet could run your code to reproduce the problem. At the very least, you should inspect the `items` variable and hardcode its value to whatever causes the error so that it's replicable for people.

Comment: If a zone fails to be retrieved, you will print out the `items` from the previous zone again.

Comment: @jasonharper but this still happens if only one zone is in the list. It stops happening when you remove the list and use a hard coded value. Why?

Comment: After further investigation, what seems to be happening is if the script runs into a zone that has no servers in it, it repeats the list of servers from the previous zone that had servers in it. I'm not sure why that's happening. @PranavHosangadi this seems to be a problem with the logic of this one function. So I'm not sure a minimal, reproducible example will be of help especially as one would need access to a GCP account (that not everyone has) to be completely reproducible. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you give the function a list of zones with JUST zones that have servers in it, the problem does not occur.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the problem is solved. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was setting the `items` variable wrong.

Changing that variable from `items = result['items']` to `items = result.get('items')` solved this problem.

Here is the finished function:

```
def list_instances(compute,project_ids,gcp_zones,date):
    delete_from_collection(date)
    for project_id in project_ids:
        for zone in gcp_zones:
            print(f"Project ID: {project_id}")
            print(f"ZONE: {zone}")
            result = compute.instances().list(project=project_id, zone=zone, filter='status=running').execute()
            items = result.get('items')
            if items:
                for item in items:
                    instance_id = item['id']
                    name = item['name']
                    print(f"Name of the instance is: {name}")
                    timestamp = item['creationTimestamp']
                    private_ip = item['networkInterfaces'][0]['networkIP']
                    instance_dict = {'Project ID': project_id, 'Instance ID': instance_id, 'Name': name,'Network Interfaces': private_ip,'Timestamp': timestamp,}
                    insert_coll(instance_dict,date)
```